# How to do highcharts in coldFusion?

Tags: highcharts, coldfusion

i am new in ColdFusion and i want to do highcharts in coldFusion.

I have code like to below to display my pie chart but i dunno why it cannot be displayed. I edit it based on the example in the higcharts demo.

```html
<cfscript>
categories = [{name='Jane',y=13},{name='John',y=23},{name='Joe',y=19}];
</cfscript>

<html>

<head> 
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data:<cfoutput>#categories#</cfoutput>
    });
});
</script> 

</head>

<body>

 <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: No, no we won't. Try something yourself, if it doesn't work, we can look at what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

So in your example you create a ColdFusion array of structs here:

```
<cfscript>
categories = [{name='Jane',y=13},{name='John',y=23},{name='Joe',y=19}];
</cfscript>
```

When you pass that data to Highcharts you are outputting the ColdFusion array here:

```
data:<cfoutput>#categories#</cfoutput>
```

This will not work. The ColdFusion array is a complex variable so you can't just output it like that. If you view the source of your page you'll probably see a ColdFusion error. Try this instead:

```
data:<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(categories)#</cfoutput>;
```

That will convert your ColdFusion array into JSON, which the JavaScript can read and understand. For example:

```
[{"Y":13,"NAME":"Jane"},{"Y":23,"NAME":"John"},{"Y":19,"NAME":"Joe"}]
```

Note that the keys are uppercase - this is because ColdFusion by default uses uppercase keys. If you need lowercase keys, then when you create the ColdFusion array of structs, quote the keys. For example:

```
<cfscript>
categories = [{'name'='Jane','y'=13},{'name'='John','y'=23},{'name'='Joe','y'=19}];
</cfscript>
```

This will output JSON which looks like this:

```
[{"y":13,"name":"Jane"},{"y":23,"name":"John"},{"y":19,"name":"Joe"}]
```

Comment: Highcharts need lowercase keys for this data to work, so quote the keys for sure.

Comment: view the source of your page - does it look like you expect? Are there any errors? Have a look in the JS console for errors.